# listView color in android

Tags: android, listview, textcolor

Hai!
  In my application i want to change the listView text color in android.
How can i achieve this.
any solution will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom Adapter to do this. This tutorial looks pretty good: [custom list view](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 1):

ListView uses some optimizations when displaying itself, so you have to take some care when changing colors: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html